# Parse executable console output in batch file

Tags: java, windows, parsing, batch-file, pid

So im running this command to find the java process thats running my JAR.

```
wmic.exe process where "name like '%java%'" get processid,commandline | find "myjar.jar"
```

The console output of the above command looks like this:

```
javaw  -jar "\myjar.jar"  1932
```

How can i parse this output so I can use the process id 1932 to kill it using:

```
TASKKILL /PID 1932
```

Comment: Try `wmic process where "name like '%java%' and CommandLine like '%myjar.jar%'" get processid` Parsing the output will be much easier. `find` is not needed. If using in a batch file don't forget to double up the percent signs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't need to get the `PID`, or use `TaskKill`, `WMIC` can do it directly for you.

From the command line:

```bat
WMIC Process Where "CommandLine Like '%myjar.jar%'" Call Terminate >Nul 2>&1
```

From a batch file you need to double the percent characters:

```bat
@WMIC Process Where "CommandLine Like '%%myjar.jar%%'" Call Terminate >Nul 2>&1
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be very primitive implementation, but it will get the process number for you.
Try this following code:

```
String output = "javaw  -jar \"\\myjar.jar\"  1932";
String[] res = output.split("\\s");
System.out.println(res[res.length-1]);
```

The result of the print out will be "1932".

I assume that you know how to get output from a console application run fro Java. If not I can help with that as well.

Comment: That's not valid for a [tag:batch] file. Maybe valid Java, but that was not asked here.

Comment: I see, I assumed it was a question about Java code.